# Как вывести все значения n, а не наименьшее?

Tags: c

Вот готовая программа, но она выводит наименьшее значение, а нужны все значения n, соответствующие условию[image: условие задачи]

```
int main()
{   
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    int n;
    double a;
    printf("Введите вещественное число (a > 1) a = ");
    scanf("%lf", &a);
    if( a < 1)
    {
        printf("a < 1 !!!");
    }
    else
    {
        double sum = 0;
        for(n = 1; sum < a; n++)
            {
                sum += 1.0/n;
            }
        printf("%d : %lf", n, sum);
    }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Таких значений бесконечно много. Выводить все? :) Только я так, по секрету скажу - если взять `a` хоть немного побольше - то жизни не хватит так считать :(

Comment: В том-то и дело, что сумма гармонического ряда равна бесконечности, но разве это объяснишь преподавателю? :( Задание есть задание...

Comment: «но разве это объяснишь преподавателю?» — да, объяснишь.

Comment: Ну если ему нужна программа - просто выводите в бесконечном цикле, ему надоест :) Если в печатном - попросите для начала пару тонн бумаги и соответствующее количество порошка. Но проще - подойдите к преподавателю и поясните - ну не может же он быть полным идиотом...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение. Кол-во выводимых значений ограничено максимальным значением переменной n.

```
    int main(void) {

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

int n;
double a;
printf("Введите вещественное число (a > 1) a = ");
scanf("%lf", &a);
if (a < 1)
{
    printf("a < 1 !!!");
}
else
{
    double sum = 0;
    for (n = 1; sum <= a; n++)
    {
        sum += 1.0 / n;
    }
    do 
    {
        printf("%d : %lf, ", n, sum);
        n++;
        sum += 1.0 / n;
    } 
    while (n < INT_MAX);
}
return 0;
```

}